why is my electron app with google authenticator always returning false even when the token is correct?
In this code i send a request to the main procces to generate a qrcode from a secret using using speakeasy and qrcode
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async function() {
    const data = await ipcRenderer.invoke('generate-qrcode')
    image.setAttribute("src", data)
})

Here in the main procces it generates a secret code and returns the qrcode to then be put into the image
var secret = speakeasy.generateSecret({
    name: "Auth"
})
console.log(secret.ascii)

ipcMain.handle('generate-qrcode', async () => {
    const data = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        qrcode.toDataURL(secret.otpauth_url, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err)
            } else {
                resolve(data)
            }
        })
    })

    return data
})

The user than has an option to input the authenticator code and sends the inputed code to the main procces to handle the verification
if (e.key === 'Enter') {
   const code = Array.from(inputs).map(input => input.value).join('');
   ipcRenderer.send('verify-code', code)
}

In the main process the code gets verified
ipcMain.on('verify-code', (event, code) => {
    var verified = speakeasy.totp.verify({
        secret: secret.ascii,
        encoding: "ascii",
        token: code
    })
    console.log(code + " " + verified)
})

But even if the code is correct it always returns False no matter what

The clock on my computer was 3 minutes ahead of the clock on my phone, that's why it always returned false
